Resident time and Purity of your Product
I ask for resident time in reactor and purity of hydrogen peroxide you produce in CN110342469B, and how if i use air for raw material, not pure oxygen. thankyou.

I'm sorry, but you are not communicating with the patent authors on this site. Technology questions are off topic.
